# Which Jersey on Tomcat?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

i'm looking into Restful services and have no prior experience 
with Restful services.

i downloaded Jersey 2.1 from [here](https://jersey.java.net/download.html) 
 and put all the jars that came out of the bundle 
into the project build path. 
however, several types that i thought 
should be in there didn't come out. for one thing, the class `WebResource` isn't anywhere in the jars while 
i've got the annotations, like `@Path, @POST` etc.

when i look up `Webresource` in [findmaven](http://www.findmaven.net/find/noexactclass/WebResource/1), 
i see it in `com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:1.19:jar`.

do i need this `com.sun.jersey` jars as well, or should i only go with 
`com.sun.jersey` and just ignore the ones in the bundle `jaxrs-ri`-- the ones from https://jersey.java.net/download.html?

`jaxrs-ri` classes, say, the ones in `jersey-common.jar` are all in `glassfish` packages. 
is this what i'm missing? i haven't Glassfish in my development environment-- running it all on Tomcat.

TIA.

Comment: Why don't you use Maven? Maybe this tutorial helps you: http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/restful-web-services-example-in-java-with-jersey-spring-and-mybatis/

Comment: @bigdestroyer i was looking to sort the basics out, gain some familiarity before mixing in maven-- i'll be developing it in maven.  but what's maven gonna give me? is it easier to integrate it in maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you come by a Jersey tutorial and it is using Jersey 1.x, simply skip it. The link you provided is for the Jersey 2.x distribution. Jersey 2.x and 1.x are completely incompatible.

Jersey 1.x is all `com.sun.jersey` and 2.x is all `org.glassfish.jersey`. That's the easiest way to tell the difference, aside from the jar versions.

Personally I wouldn't even bother with tutorials. The link you provided has to the [official user guide](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/index.html). If you really want to learn Jersey, the user guide is the best place. They have really good documentation. Also you can download all the examples from the same link. The examples are referred to throughout the user guide.

- For Jersey 2.x client, see [Chapter 5. Client API](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html)
- For JSON support, which you will probably need (as the distribution doesn't come with JSON support jars), see [Chapter 9. Support for Common Media Type Representations](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html)

Since you already know Maven, if I were you, I would start from the very beginning of the User Guide. It will show you a Maven archetype to get started really quick. I use this archetype all the time.

And yes, Jersey 2.x will work just fine on Tomcat. `org.glassfish.jersey` has nothing to do with the compatibility. It's just a package name change with the major version.

Comment: Nothing's wrong with it. That's like asking what's wrong with Java 7. Java 8 has new features, same with Jersey 2.x. Only difference is Jersey 1.x and Jersey 2.x are _completely_ incompatible

Comment: ok. would i be missing too much if i go w/1.x? i set it up since and everything looks ok.

Comment: Personally, I think you would be missing out on alot. That's just me. It depends on what you need. Also the Jersey [1.x documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/user-guide.html) is not at good as 2.x. You can scan through both user guides to get an idea of what each one provides and make the decision for yourself. Is there a reason you seem to be preferring Jersey 1.x?